# How to type <X> without spaces?

Tags: support, markdown

I would like to type

< X >

without the spaces. Doing so (at least without the first space) yields no character at all.

Typing the same in code mode works:

```
<X>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<x> could work

Use plain html if the markdown parser doesn't behave like you want to

> ```
> &lt;x>
> ```

See [What HTML tags are allowed on Stack Exchange sites?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/135909/158100) and [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/122657/158100) from [slhck](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/159624/slhck)

Answer (score 3):

Use [html character entity references](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references#Character_entity_references_in_HTML) so for < type &lt; and for > type &gt;

So if you type this &lt;X&gt; you'd see it as this: <X>